# Selecting percentage of group and population based on a field in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with user IDs and states. I need to assign 20% of users in each state to a control group by setting a flag in another table. I don't know how I would be able to ensure that the numbers are correct though. How would I go about even starting this?

Answer (score 1):

As an example, take a look at this sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e49d/6/0

```
with counts as
 (select stateid, count(userid) as num_users
    from userstates
   group by stateid)
select *
  from (select x.stateid,
               x.userid,
               sum(1) over(partition by x.stateid order by x.userid) as runner,
               y.num_users,
               sum(1) over(partition by x.stateid order by x.userid) / y.num_users as pct
          from userstates x
          join counts y
            on x.stateid = y.stateid)
 where pct <= .2
```

There are a couple of assumptions I made:

-- I assumed that, if you could not pull exactly 20%, you would choose, for instance, 19%, rather than 21%. The query would need to be changed slightly if you want to pull 1 ID over 20% when exactly 20% is not possible (you can't pull a fraction of a username, so you have to choose one way or the other).

-- I assumed that you did not want a random 20%, and that 20% of the first user IDs, in order, would suffice. I would need to change the query slightly if you wanted the 20% from each group to be random.